# When can connect() on O_NONBLOCK socket fail with something other than EINPROGRESS or EALREADY?

Tags: sockets, unix, posix, portability, errno

I read the following sample code and I am wondering if anybody can say on which platforms it is possible for `connect()` to fail with something other than EINPROGRESS or EALREADY.

By fail I mean execute the `else` branch in the sample to execute. The comment in the source suggests FreeBSD. Are there any other systems? I was not able to get it to fail on Linux.

```c
        if (connect(hostp->sockets[i],
            (struct sockaddr *)res->ai_addr,
            res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            /* This is what we expect. */
            if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
                printf("    connect EINPROGRESS OK "
                    "(expected)\n");
                FD_SET(hostp->sockets[i], &wrfds);
            } else {
                /*
                 * This may happen right here, on
                 * localhost for example (immediate
                 * connection refused).
                 * I can see that happen on FreeBSD
                 * but not on Solaris, for example.
                 */
                printf("    connect: %s\n",
                    strerror(errno));
                ++n;
            }
        [...]
```

source: http://mff.devnull.cz/pvu/src/tcp/non-blocking-connect.c

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways why connect might fail. As the comment rightly says even a non-blocking connect might fail immediately on some platforms when connecting to localhost if no listening server is there. Also connect will usually fail immediately if no route can be determined to the target, for example if the interface for the default route is down. And then there are still other ways to fail, like lack of memory, permission denied to connect when running inside a sandbox or similar.

Comment: Interface being down sounds promising. I will try this next. (I am dealing with code which I think does not handle these failures correctly, and I want to write down actual reproduction steps which will make it leak file descriptors (which would happen if I can trigger the failure in the right way)).

Comment: I could not get it to fail (or succeed for that matter) immediately. I tried linux, freebsd and openindiana (half-heartedly). Still, not handling the possibility in code is definitely a bug.